# Setting value for DataGridViewRow.Tag when data binding by DataSource for DatagridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I am trying to set a value for DataGridViewRow`.Tag` when data binding but I don't know how to do it?

I tried with `DataRow row = table.NewRow();` But row doesn't have tag.

How to set a value for DataGridViewRow.Tag when `binding DataGridView` to table (for example)? Or it isn't possible?

Edit1:

Here is the code i am using:

> ```
>             var table = new DataTable();
>             table.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
>             table.Columns.Add("URL", typeof(string));
>             table.Columns.Add("Read Later", typeof(bool));
>             foreach (XElement node in nodes)
>             {
>                 Helper.CheckNode(node);
>
>                 var id = node.Attribute("id").Value;
>                 var url = node.Element("path").Value;
>                 var comment = node.Element("title").Value;
>                 var readlater = node.Attribute("readLater")?.Value.ToString() == "1";
>
>                 var row = table.NewRow();
>                 row.ItemArray = new object[] { url, comment, readlater };
>                 
>                 table.Rows.Add(row);//Edit2
>             }
>             dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
> ```

I am trying to set a tag for the row to use it in CellClick event:

> ```
>        var cRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
>        var id = cRow.Tag.ToString();
> ```

Comment: If it doesnt have a `Tag` property, then it is not possible.  Maybe if you explained what you are trying to do, we could help.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp please check my edit1

Comment: I am not following what you are trying to do, however, it looks like the rows are not getting added to the `table.` The line of code… `var row = table.NewRow();` will give a new row, however, it is not “added” to the `table`. I am pretty sure if you want to “add” that row to the `table` you need to do something like… `table.Rows.Add(row);`

Comment: @JohnG Yes, i forgot to add row to the table. I was trying to find a way to make DataGridViewRow `have a tag value` when populating the DataGridView from DataSource from table. As i need to access the tag when i click a cell. In this project i am working to make the tag of the row to have the id of the item only but other project i am working on i want the tag of the row to have many data as object class.

Comment: I could be mistaken as I am not that familiar with the `Tag` property. However, from my little research it appears your code is going to have to loop through each grid row and set each row’s `Tag` property. I do not see anything that will “automatically” set each row’s `Tag` value when the grids `DataSource` is set. Again, I may be wrong about this. I am not understanding what values you want the `Tag` to contain. If the row is associated with some other object, could you not “grab” the associated object when the cell is clicked as opposed adding the object as a `Tag`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnG I may be able to loop if I have datasourece as list but i have it as table so i may can't. I also couldn't find anything to help me when i searched the internet. I can't get the object when i click the cell, it have to be in the row itself. But i will add another column and put the the object in it as object class with override ToString and it will search as tag. I think it is the best option as i can see. I already tested with int value to add it in a column and it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your comment… _”I may be able to loop if I have datasourece as list but i have it as table so i may can't.”_ … ? … Why not? … You can loop through the table’s rows.

Comment: … _”I can't get the object when i click the cell, it have to be in the row itself.”_ …? … The “Cell” “belongs” to a “Row” and has a `RowIndex` property.

Comment: If you want the “object” instead of a `DataRow`… Is there some reason you don’t use a `List<yourObject>` as a data source to the grid? Can you describe how the row in the grids data source is related to its tag? Could you not simply add the object to each row and not display its properties? It is difficult to visualize what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have some projects that i need to populate DataGridView and for now i set it to enable `virtual mode` to the DataGridView. Which works good but this requite the developer to set each cell's content which is fine. But lately i learned about DataSource and i found it easier to use than virtual mode. I am learning C# by myself and i am not pro in it.

Comment: I usually make an object class that has properties about an item in my database that has info not included in the cells at the DGV. For example: as i have note taking software i put in the tag properties if the note is locked, password protected, background color, etc. Also i have launcher software that i have this properties in the tag: is the item is file, folder, software or website, the group the item belong to, OpenWith software and working directory for the item.

Comment: I can't loop because if i loop i will do the same works twice as i will read from the source and populate the tag for every row which i am trying to avoid.

Comment: I am trying to do it by DataTable and find a way to add a tag for rows. For now i use list with virtual mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Separate the data from how it is displayed

When using a DataGridView, it is seldom a good idea to access the cells and the columns directly. It is way more easier to use `DataGridView.DataSource`.

In modern programming there is a tendency to separate your data (= model) from the way your data is displayed (= view). To glue these two items together an adapter class is needed, which is usually called the viewmodel. Abbreviated these three items are called MVVM.

### Use DataGridView.DataSource to display the data

Apparently, if the operator clicks a cell, you want to read the value of the tag of the row of the cell, to get some extra information, some Id.

This displayed row is the display of some data. Apparently part of the functionality of this data is access to this Id. You should not put this information in the view, you should put it in the model.

```
class MyWebPage                        // TODO: invent proper identifier
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Url {get; set;}
    public bool ReadLater {get; set;}

    ... // other properties
}
```

Apparently you have a method to fetch the data that you want to display from a sequence of `nodes`. Separate fetching this data (=model) from displaying it (= view):

```
IEnumerable<MyWebPage> FetchWebPages(...)
{
    ...
    foreach (XElement node in nodes)
    {
        Helper.CheckNode(node);

        bool readLater = this.CreateReadLater(node);
        yield return new MyWebPage
        {
            Id = node.Attribute("id").Value,
            Url = node.Element("path").Value,
            Title = node.Element("title").Value,
            ReadLater = this.CreateReadLater(node),
        };
    }
}
```

I don't know what is in node "ReadLater", apparently you know how to convert it to a Boolean.

```
bool CreateReadLater(XElement node)
{
     // TODO: implement, if null return true; if not null ...
     // out of scope of this question
}
```

For every property that you want to display you create a DataGridViewColumn. Property [DataPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname?view=net-5.0) defines which property should be shown in the column. Use [DefaultCellStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle?view=net-5.0) if a standard ToString is not enough to display the value properly, for instance, to define the number of digits after the decimal point, or to color negative values red.

You can do this using the visual studio designer, or you can do this in the constructor:

```
public MyForm
{
    InitializeComponents();
    this.dataGridViewColumnTitle.DataPropertyName = nameof(MyWebPage.Title);
    this.dataGridViewColumnUrl.DataPropertyName = nameof(MyWebPage.Url);
    ...
}
```

You don't want to display the Id, so there is no column for this.

Now to display the data, all you have to do is assign the list to the datasource:

```
this.dataGrieViewWebPages.DataSource = this.FetchWebPages().ToList();
```

This is display only. If the operator can change the displayed values, and you want to access the changed values, you should put the items in an object that implements interface [IBindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist?view=net-5.0), for instance, using class (surprise!) `BindingList<T>`:

```
private BindingList<MyWebPage> DisplayedWebPages
{
    get => (BindingList<MyWebPage>)this.dataGrieViewWebPages.DataSource;
    set => this.dataGrieViewWebPages.DataSource = value;
}
```

Initialization:

```
private void DisplayWebPages()
{
    this.DisplayedWebPages = new BindingList<MyWebPage>(this.FetchWebPages.ToList());
}
```

And presto! All webpages are displayed. Every change that the operator makes: add / remove / edit rows are automatically updated in the DisplayedWebPages.

If you want to access the currently selected WebPages:

```
private MyWebPage CurrentWebPage =>(MyWebPage)this.dataGrieViewWebPages.CurrentRow?.DataBoundItem;

private IEnumerable<MyWebPage> SelectedWebPages =>
    this.dataGrieViewWebPages.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<MyWebPage>();
```

Now apparently whenever the operator clicks a cell, you want to do something with the Id of the WebPage that is displayed in the Row of the cell.

- **View**: Displayed Cell and Row
- **ViewModel**: React when operator clicks a cell
- **Model** Action that must be done

### React on Cell Click: get the Id

We've handled the View above. ViewModel is the event handler:

```
void OnDatGridViewCellClicked(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // use the eventArgs to fetch the row, and thus the WebPage:
    MyWebPage webPage = (MyWebPage)this.dataGridViewWebPages.Rows[e.RowIndow].DataBoundItem;
    this.ProcessWebPage(webPage);
}
```

ProcessWebPage is typically a method in your Model class:

```
public void ProcessWebPage(MyWebPage webPage)
{
     // Do what you need to do if the operator clicks the cell, for example:
     int webPageId = webPage.Id;
     ...
}
```

### Conclusion: advantages of separating model from view

By the way, did you see that all ViewModel methods are one-liners? Only your Model methods `FetchWebPages` and ProcessWebPage contain several lines.

Because you separated the View from the Model, changes to your Model or your View will be fairly simple:

- If you want to store your data in Json format, or in a database instead of in an XML, your View won't change
- If you don't want to react on cell click, but on Button OK click, then your Model won't change. Your model also doesn't have to change if you decide to show more or less columns
- Because you separated your Model from your View, the Model can be unit tested without a form. You can also test the View with a Model filled with only test values.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help, I learned something new today. I have a question, when i delete/add/or edit a row in my XML (or database) i still have to call this line to show the changes, right? `DisplayWebPages()` As i tried and deleted an entry in my XML file and it still in the rows in my DataGridView.

Comment: I can see from my tests that when i edit an item in the list and i call `DisplayWebPages()` to show the edit on the list, it scrolls to the top. It acts like i cleared all the rows and added new ones. When i used `dataSource = table` i didn't see this problem datagridview changes and stays at the current state without scrolling. Is there anything i can do to prevent the scrolling when i edit a row? I edit it like this `var row = ((BindingList<WebPage>)dataGridView1.DataSource).OfType<WebPage>().Where(w => w.Url == url).Cast<WebPage>().FirstOrDefault();` then `row.Title = title;`

Comment: If you only change / add / remove a few items of the bindinglist, don't create a new one, just add / remove / change the items. The display is automatically updated.